# How to implement unmanaged callback functions in C#?

Tags: c#, c

How can I implement the C# code below? This is a callback function from an unmanaged C/C++ DLL.

```
extern void (*NdProcSamples)(word dc, word phase, word sum_st, const NdPackChan *chans);//This function is in Third party(C/C++ DLL).

typedef void (*TProcSamples)(word dc, word phase, word sum_st, const NdPackChan *chans); //Call back Fucntion

TProcSamples *pProcSamples;

pProcSamples = (TProcSamples*) GetProcAddress(drv_lib, "NdProcSamples") //Gets address of function

*pProcSamples = NdProcSamples;

// Function below gets called by driver(DLL)

void NdProcSamples(word dc, word phase, word sum_st, const NdPackChan *chans)
{

    //logic goes here 

}
```

Comment: Do you know what the calling convention is?

Comment: This question is a little bit unclear. How are you going to pass this callback to unmanaged code?
But anyways, you can safely use `delegate` and pass it to unmanaged functions, just remember that C# has `__stdcall` calling convention by default. Please provide more code if you want a full answer.